# NoMethodError when calling children.text from a loop, but it works outside of the loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape the data from a table, and I'm unable to figure out why I can't iterate through the data gathered.

I'd like to iterate through each node in the table, getting the text within but the statement only works if written outside my loop.

[Take a look at the terminal I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRHTQ.png)

It's clear that `puts` outside of the loop works fine, but the same line fails in the loop. If I use

```
puts entry.children[1]
```

I get the proper response in the loop, but adding `children.text` is what causes it to fail:

```
require 'HTTParty'
require 'Nokogiri'
require 'JSON'
require 'Pry'
require 'CSV'

module Guns
  class Scraper
    page = HTTParty.get('http://www.gunviolencearchive.org/last-72-hours')

    parse_page = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
    incidents = Array.new
    raw_table = parse_page.css('#block-system-main').css('.sticky-enabled')
    table_entries = raw_table.xpath('//tbody')[0].children
    state = table_entries.children[1].children.text
    puts table_entries.children[1].children.text

    table_entries.each do |entry|
      puts entry.children[1].children.text
    end
    Pry.start(binding)
  end
end
```

I might be able to do string slicing on the client side of the final program if I can't solve this problem but I'd rather not have to.

Comment: It's idiomatic to fold the names of the gems you're including to lower-case. Instead of making us look at an image of the error, you should copy/paste the essential/important part of the error as text into your question, formatting it appropriately. Links rot and break and when they do your question won't make much sense. See "[mcve]". Also, we need the absolute minimal HTML that _you_ extracted from the page that demonstrates the problem _in the question itself_.

Answer (score 0):

The `table_entries` object is equal to nil, or `table_entries.children[1]` is equal to nil. As a result you are calling the children method on `nil` which does not define the `children` method. You might be tempted to use the `try` method like this:

```
table_entries.children[1].try(:children).try(:text)
```

But unless you know why these values are `nil` and can confirm that they are not detrimental to the design of the app you are just allowing your code to fail silently.

Comment: That still confuses me though. I know that's what the terminal says and I have no doubt that something is causing that to happen, but why would the same statement using the same reference work outside of the loop?

I assuming there's something I don't understand about the way ruby loops are declared, or what is the actual value of the table_entries variable.

For the record all I want is to rip the table on this page http://www.gunviolencearchive.org/last-72-hours write that to a csv.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?